# Use WITH inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, select, db2

I am trying to use a `WITH` in a stored procedure, but am failing. My assumption was that I could use `WITH` as part of my `SELECT` statement; now I am unsure as to if it is possible and I'm doing it wrong, or if it is not possible.

I've tried both of the following, but both throw an error on the `AS` following the `WITH`

Attempt 1:

```
SET p_temp = (
    WITH
        temp (id) AS (
            SELECT orgs.id
            FROM orgstruct.tOrgs AS orgs
            WHERE orgs.prnt = p_OrgID
        )
    SELECT 1
    FROM temp
    FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY);
```

Attempt 2:

```
IF EXISTS (
        WITH
            temp (id) AS (
                SELECT orgs.id
                FROM orgstruct.tOrgs AS orgs
                WHERE orgs.prnt = p_OrgID
            )
        SELECT 1
        FROM temp) THEN
    SET p_temp = 1;
END IF;
```

Is the only solution to create a view for each `WITH` I would normally want to use?

Comment: See this http://www.orafaq.com/node/1879

Comment: I'm having no problem executing the queries from the command line, the problem is when I try to use the same query in a stored procedure. This is the source of my confusion: a `SELECT` statement without a `WITH` is fine, but with a `WITH` throws an error when trying to create the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with the following:

```
DECLARE p_exists SMALLINT;

DECLARE c1 CURSOR
    WITHOUT HOLD
    WITHOUT RETURN
    FOR
        WITH
            cte AS (SELECT x FROM y)
        SELECT 1
        FROM cte
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
    FOR READ ONLY
    OPTIMIZE FOR 1 ROWS;
OPEN c1;
SET p_exists = 0;
FETCH c1 INTO p_exists;
CLOSE c1;
```

`p_exists` is 1 if one or more records existed, and is otherwise 0.
I had hoped to avoid using a cursor, but it's still preferable to views.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
with cte as
(
SELECT COUNT(orgs.id) as cte_result 
            FROM orgstruct.tOrgs AS orgs
            WHERE orgs.prnt = p_OrgID
) 
select 
    case 
        when cte.cte_result > 0 
            then '>0' 
        else '=0' 
    end
from cte
```

Returns '>0' or '=0' as the result.

Definitely no need for views or cursors...

Answer (score 0):

If your expression is really just returning a scalar value based on the presence of matching rows, that can be done inside your stored procedure without using a CTE:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orgstruct.tOrgs AS orgs WHERE orgs.prnt = p_OrgID ) )
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END 
INTO p_exists
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
;
```

For more sophisticated queries that really do require CTEs, you also have the option of embedding the CTEs inside a user-defined function, and then calling the function from the stored procedure.